# Change Iterable[(String, Double)] of an RDD to Array or List

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Double, Double), Iterable[(String, Double)])]` but it seems working with the `Iterable` is hard. Is there any way I can change it to an `Array[(String, Double)]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use `Iterable.toArray`

```
rdd.map{case (x, y, iter) => (x, y, iter.toArray)}
```

or `Iterable.toList`

```
rdd.map{case (x, y, iter) => (x, y, iter.toList)}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Is there any advantage to using the Array over the List or vice-versa?

Comment: List and Array will have different performance characteristics. Array will generally perform better for random access, worse if you need to grow the collection and can do so by pre-pending new items to it.